# Python - idxmax for 2nd, 3rd, n-th largest in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I am using the following command to get the max element:

```
print("%.2f" % total_returns['return 5 days ago'].max(), total_returns['return 5 days ago'].idxmax(), "5 days max")
```

is there a way to get the 2nd, 3rd etc. largest as well?

```
total_returns.head()
Out[15]: 
          first close last close  ... date 1250 days ago  date 1500 days ago
S&P 500       1469.25    2893.06  ...         2014-10-20          2013-10-22
Tesla           23.89     327.71  ...         2014-11-07          2013-11-11
Apple         3.67188     249.05  ...         2014-11-07          2013-11-11
Microsoft      58.375     144.19  ...         2014-11-07          2013-11-11
Amazon         76.125    1777.08  ...         2014-11-07          2013-11-11

[5 rows x 47 columns]
```

Comment: Sorry, but how method `nlargest` return index like `idxmax` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are using `pandas.DataFrame`.

In that case, you can use [pandas.DataFrame.nlargest](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html)

```
n=3
total_returns.nlargest(n, 'return 5 days ago')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with `ascending=False` and then select by indexing for 2th and 3rd largest value with index:

```
print (total_returns[['first close']])
           first close
S&P 500     1469.25000
Tesla         23.89000
Apple          3.67188
Microsoft     58.37500
Amazon        76.12500

s = total_returns['first close'].sort_values(ascending=False)
print (s)
S&P 500      1469.25000
Amazon         76.12500
Microsoft      58.37500
Tesla          23.89000
Apple           3.67188
Name: first close, dtype: float64

print("%.2f" % s.iloc[1], 
               s.index[1], "2nd largest")
76.12 Amazon 2nd largest

print("%.2f" % s.iloc[2], 
               s.index[2], "3rd largest")
58.38 Microsoft 3rd largest
```